# How can I reduce this redirect chain? Or at least, how can I make certain parts serverside?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns, redirect

I have the following redirect chain which is based on the let's encrypt force ssl setting, my CMS's automated language redirect and my www redirect.

```
example.com -> http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com ->  https://www.example.com/en
```

The server is Ubuntu 16.4 running on Apache 2.4.34. I'll gladly provide any required additional information.

I am aware that I could drop the www. but that should be the last resort. I highly prefer the looks of the domain with the www and for certain online businesses I like to think that it adds an amount of professionalism to the appearance, if that makes any sense.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on


#Domain: www.example.com
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Images
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]

# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/font-woff .woff
AddType font/woff2 .woff2
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/woff2 "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/otf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset Etag
</IfModule>
FileETag none
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript font/ttf application/x-font-ttf font/otf application/x-font-otf font/opentype image/svg+xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404
```

I've tried adding:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

To my .htaccess and it did the following according to redirectdetective.com.

- it removed the cookie from example.com
- it changed the redirect from    example.com -> http://www.example.com/ to be 301 instead of 302

However the gtmetrix score became even lower and according to tools.keycdn.com/performance the TTFB became even worse. Which mayhaps just've been the related to servers or other variables.

Comment: It depends on how you have your redirect setup. You can easily combine forcing SSL and www. into just one rule.

Comment: How would I go about this? I literally just agreed to Let's encrypt's proposal of enforcing ssl, added www as an alias of my domain via cname and pointed my CMS to run on the www version and my CMS automatically asigns the corresponding language ending depending on the browser's language. I've added my .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

OK so right now you have the following in your `.htaccess` to force www and https:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

We can immediately cut this down to one condition and one rewriterule and therefore reduce the amount of time the server spends loading the web pages:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

So the `RewriteCond` is checking for both `exmaple.com` and `www.example.com`, that is what `(www\.)?` is there for, checking for both. The `RewriteRule` then forces the change of `https://www` and it does this for all directories. You can test this here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=c49d8857-763d-560b-8e5f-7258fc97e96b now it is only making one request to the server, not two.

Make sure you clear your cache ***before*** testing this.

In regards to your language change, there isn't anything you can do to make this run more efficiently. Either way the server needs to check the users proffered language and then load that version of the website.

Looking at your `.htaccess` I see a lot of rules in relation to images, but I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here? This will be slowing down your loading time. I would look at these rules, are they really needed?

I hope this helps.